# subtract 2 values from the same table with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, union, subtraction

I hope I can get some help here since i cannot think of anything else.

so i have 2 results that come from the same table which i want to see in one query... so i used UNION, all good until there, now i need the difference between these two results. Let's say i have the next result:

```
measure         30_days
old_purchases   342     
new_purchases   54
```

i need a new row that gives me the difference between those two, something like that:

```
measure         30_days   
old_purchases   342      
new_purchases   54      
difference      288
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select measure, value
from t
union all
select 'difference',
       sum(case when measure = 'old_purchases' then value
                when measure = 'new_purchases' then - value
                else 0
           end)
from t;
```

If you actually want to add this to the table then use `insert`:

```
insert into t (measure, value)
    select 'difference',
           sum(case when measure = 'old_purchases' then value
                    when measure = 'new_purchases' then - value
                    else 0
               end)
    from t;
```

Comment: @Caro_ml1 . . . This answers the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, please ask as a *new* question.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! my mind was so blocked! you saved my day! :) wish u all the best!